# error when try to manage all entities of a class

Tags: php, entity-framework, yii

i get this error when i try to do an admin action for list all entity instantiated of a specific class:

> include(authenticate.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
>   /home/user/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(423)

```
{
412                             include($classFile);
413                             if(YII_DEBUG && basename(realpath($classFile))!==$className.'.php')
414                                 throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Class name "{class}" does not match class file "{file}".', array(
415                                     '{class}'=>$className,
416                                     '{file}'=>$classFile,
417                                 )));
418                             break;
419                         }
420                     }
421                 }
422                 else
423                     include($className.'.php');
424             }
425             else  // class name with namespace in PHP 5.3
426             {
427                 $namespace=str_replace('\\','.',ltrim($className,'\\'));
428                 if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($namespace))!==false)
429                     include($path.'.php');
430                 else
431                     return false;
432             }
433             return class_exists($className,false) || interface_exists($className,false);
434         }
435         return true;
```

CGridView in admin file of view folder

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'utente-crea-evento-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'status',
        'username',
        'password', other properties
```

admin action

```
public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new UtenteCreaEvento('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['UtenteCreaEvento']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['UtenteCreaEvento'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

more stack trace info

```
#0  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(423): YiiBase::autoload()
#1  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(298): YiiBase::autoload("authenticate")
#2  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/validators/CValidator.php(187): YiiBase::import("authenticate", true)
#3  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/base/CModel.php(285): CValidator::createValidator("authenticate", UtenteCreaEvento, "password", array())
#4  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/base/CModel.php(259): CModel->createValidators()
#5  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(1871): CModel->getValidators("numTel")
#6  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(1217): CHtml::activeInputField("text", UtenteCreaEvento, "numTel", array("name" => "UtenteCreaEvento[numTel]", "id" => "UtenteCreaEvento_numTel"))
#7  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/widgets/CActiveForm.php(658): CHtml::activeTextField(UtenteCreaEvento, "numTel", array())
#8  
–  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utenteCreaEvento/_search.php(42): CActiveForm->textField(UtenteCreaEvento, "numTel")
37         <?php echo $form->textField($model,'cognome',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
38     </div>
39 
40     <div class="row">
41         <?php echo $form->label($model,'numTel'); ?>
42         <?php echo $form->textField($model,'numTel'); ?>
43     </div>
44 
45     <div class="row">
46         <?php echo $form->label($model,'numEventiCreati'); ?>
47         <?php echo $form->textField($model,'numEventiCreati'); ?>
#9  
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CBaseController.php(127): require("/home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utente...")
#10 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CBaseController.php(96): CBaseController->renderInternal("/home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utente...", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento), true)
#11 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(870): CBaseController->renderFile("/home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utente...", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento), true)
#12 
–  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utenteCreaEvento/admin.php(40): CController->renderPartial("_search", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento))
35 
36 <?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
37 <div class="search-form" style="display:none">
38 <?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
39     'model'=>$model,
40 )); ?>
41 </div><!-- search-form -->
42 
43 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
44     'id'=>'utente-crea-evento-grid',
45     'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
#13 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CBaseController.php(127): require("/home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utente...")
#14 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CBaseController.php(96): CBaseController->renderInternal("/home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utente...", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento), true)
#15 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(870): CBaseController->renderFile("/home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/views/utente...", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento), true)
#16 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(783): CController->renderPartial("admin", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento), true)
#17 
–  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/protected/controllers/UtenteCreaEventoController.php(146): CController->render("admin", array("model" => UtenteCreaEvento))
141         if(isset($_GET['UtenteCreaEvento']))
142             $model->attributes=$_GET['UtenteCreaEvento'];
143 
144         $this->render('admin',array(
145             'model'=>$model,
146         ));
147     }
148 
149     /**
150      * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
151      * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
#18 */
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(50): UtenteCreaEventoController->actionAdmin()
#19 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(309): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array())
#20 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(134): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#21 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilter.php(41): CFilterChain->run()
#22 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(1146): CFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
#23 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/filters/CInlineFilter.php(59): CController->filterAccessControl(CFilterChain)
#24 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(131): CInlineFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
#25 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(292): CFilterChain->run()
#26 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array("accessControl", "postOnly + delete"))
#27 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(283): CController->run("admin")
#28 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(142): CWebApplication->runController("utenteCreaEvento/admin")
#29 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#30 
+  /home/sigturk/NetBeansProjects/sitoEventi/index.php(13): CApplication->run()
```

model

```
class UtenteCreaEvento extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return UtenteCreaEvento the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_utenteCreaEvento';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('username, password, nome, cognome, email', 'required'),
            array('status, numTel, numEventiCreati, numFeedPositivi, statoCanone', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('username, password, nome, cognome', 'length', 'max'=>128),
                        array('password','length','min'=>6),
            array('password','authenticate'),
                        array('email', 'length', 'max'=>256),
            array('email', 'email'),
                        array('numTel, numEventiCreati, numFeedPositivi, statoCanone','safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, status, username, nome, cognome, numTel, numEventiCreati, numFeedPositivi, email, statoCanone, dataCreazioneProfilo', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'eventiCreati' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Evento', 'creatoDa'),
            'fotoCaricate' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Foto', 'caricataDaUtenteEventi'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'nome' => 'Nome',
            'cognome' => 'Cognome',
            'numTel' => 'Num Tel',
            'numEventiCreati' => 'Num Eventi Creati',
            'numFeedPositivi' => 'Num Feed Positivi',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'statoCanone' => 'Stato Canone',
            'dataCreazioneProfilo' => 'Data Creazione Profilo',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
        $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
        $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
        $criteria->compare('nome',$this->nome,true);
        $criteria->compare('cognome',$this->cognome,true);
        $criteria->compare('numTel',$this->numTel);
        $criteria->compare('numEventiCreati',$this->numEventiCreati);
        $criteria->compare('numFeedPositivi',$this->numFeedPositivi);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('statoCanone',$this->statoCanone);
        $criteria->compare('dataCreazioneProfilo',$this->dataCreazioneProfilo,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

        /**
     * This is invoked before the record is saved.
     * @return boolean whether the record should be saved.
     */
    protected function beforeSave()
    {
              if ($this->isNewRecord)
                $this->dataCreazioneProfilo = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
              $this->status = 0;
              $this->statoCanone = 0;

            return parent::beforeSave();
        }
```

controller

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new UtenteCreaEvento;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['UtenteCreaEvento']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UtenteCreaEvento'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['UtenteCreaEvento']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UtenteCreaEvento'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
//      $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
                $utentecreaEvento = new UtenteCreaEvento();
                $utentecreaEvento = UtenteCreaEvento::model()->find('id',$id);
                $utentecreaEvento->status = 0;

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('UtenteCreaEvento');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new UtenteCreaEvento('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['UtenteCreaEvento']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['UtenteCreaEvento'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=UtenteCreaEvento::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param CModel the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='utente-crea-evento-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

i get this kind of error only when i try to manege the entities of this class but all other kind of actions don't gives any kind of problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't have to do anything with permissions, show is your CGridView configuration, and your admin action.

Comment: <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'utente-crea-evento-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(
  'id',
  'status',
  'username',
  'password',.....   @Asgaroth

Comment: just edit your question and add the code there. you can remove the permissions part, it is not relevant

Comment: Include more info on the stack trace, you are calling a class that is not found on the class path, we just need to find where

Comment: i use an 'authenticate' call only in the loginForm.php for authenticate my user ---> $this->_identity->authenticate(); but if i got an error in that part of program automatically i can't perform a login but i can do it without problem @Asgaroth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your validation rules you specified `array('password','authenticate'),` . So either the model should contain a function named `authenticate()` or you must add a `authenticate` class extending from `CValidator`.

Comment: i've defined, as a basic project, the class UserIdentity that exetends CuserIdentity where is defined the public function authenticate() and this class is located in the components folder. And for solve my problem is better to bring this function in the model class or in a dedicated class? thx @dInGd0nG

Comment: Sorry man but you make me think about the benefit to use the rule array('password','authenticate') . Because if i delete it from my prog i don't have the trouble write before and all work perfectly. Can you explain me for what it is useful?  @dInGd0nG